# Merge Data Frame and Expand R Column Values To Column Headers

Tags: r, merge, datatable, tidyverse

I have 2 R data frames that looks like this:

**DATA FRAME 1:**

| identifier | ef_posterior | position_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 0.260 | 1 |
| 11111 | 0.0822 | 2 |
| 11111 | 0.00797 | 3 |
| 11111 | 0.04 | 4 |
| 11111 | 0.245 | 5 |
| 11111 | 0.432 | 6 |
| 11112 | 0.342 | 1 |
| 11112 | 0.453 | 2 |
| 11112 | 0.0032 | 3 |
| 11112 | 0.241 | 5 |
| 11112 | 0.0422 | 6 |
| 11112 | 0.311 | 4 |

**DATAFRAME 2:**

| study_identifier | %LVEF |
| --- | --- |
| 11111 | 62 |
| 11112 | 76 |

I want to merge and rearrange these two data frame into something like this:
Here, study_identifier and identifier are the same thing (just different column names)

| identifier | pos_1 | pos_2 | pos_3 | pos_4 | pos_5 | pos_6 | %LVEF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 0.260 | 0.0822 | 0.00797 | 0.04 | 0.245 | 0.432 | 62 |
| 11112 | 0.342 | 0.453 | 0.0032 | 0.311 | 0.241 | 0.0422 | 76 |

How would I go about doing this?
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% mutate(position_no = paste0("position_", position_no)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = identifier, names_from = position_no, values_from = ef_posterior) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("identifier" = "study_identifier"))

# A tibble: 2 x 8
  identifier position_1 position_2 position_3 position_4 position_5 position_6  LVEF
       <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <int>
1      11111      0.26      0.0822    0.00797      0.04       0.245     0.432     62
2      11112      0.342     0.453     0.0032       0.311      0.241     0.0422    76
```

data used

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "identifier       ef_posterior    position_no
 1 11111              0.260            1    
 2 11111              0.0822           2    
 3 11111              0.00797          3    
 4 11111              0.04             4
 5 11111              0.245            5
 6 11111              0.432            6
 7 11112              0.342            1
 8 11112              0.453            2
 9 11112              0.0032           3
10 11112              0.241            5
11 11112              0.0422           6
12 11112              0.311            4", header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text = "study_identifier      LVEF    
                  1 11111              62                
                  2 11112              76", header = T)
```

Note in view of comments below-

```
#when identifier in df2 is factor
df2$study_identifier <- factor(df2$study_identifier)

#use this code

df1 %>% mutate(position_no = paste0("position_", position_no)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = identifier, names_from = position_no, values_from = ef_posterior) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% mutate(study_identifier = as.numeric(as.character(study_identifier))), by = c("identifier" = "study_identifier"))

# A tibble: 2 x 8
  identifier position_1 position_2 position_3 position_4 position_5 position_6  LVEF
       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <int>
1      11111      0.26      0.0822    0.00797      0.04       0.245     0.432     62
2      11112      0.342     0.453     0.0032       0.311      0.241     0.0422    76
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer! I think your code should do the work for me but I am getting the msg Error: Can't join on `x$identifier` x `y$identifier` because of incompatible types.
ℹ `x$identifier` is of type <factor<a7ce9>>>.
ℹ `y$identifier` is of type <integer>>. Do you have any ideas on how I can approach this issue?

Comment: Change factor to character type first and then numeric.  Do these on df2 before joining.  See edit

Comment: Problem Solved! Thank you!